# HashMap sent from view is a String object in controller

Tags: grails

1. I'm sending HashMap from controller to view:

   ```
   def list2 =  [id:params?.id, title:params?.title, domain:params?.domain, orderOfSubpage:params?.orderOfSubpage]
   render(view: "list", model: [subpageInstanceList: list, subpageInstanceTotal:  list.getTotalCount(), searchParams:list2])
   ```
2. I'm sending back this HashMap to the controller when user clicks on table header:

   ```
   <g:sortableColumn property="id" title="Id" class="td-id-class subpage-td" params="['searchParams':searchParams]"/>
   ```
3. I'm checking value in debugger where flag is set here:

   ```
   def map = params
   ```

   The value is:

   ```
   searchParams={id=, title=, domain=, orderOfSubpage=}
   ```
4. I'm trying to get values from this 'map' which is already String:

   ```
   def map2 = params?.searchParams
   def id = map2?.id //here is an Exception (checked in debugger)
   ```
5. Exception I'm getting back is:

   ```
   Class groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException
   Message No such property: id for class: java.lang.String
   ```

When I'm doing **the same thing** with ArrayList there is no problem, everything works fine and List is always List. Why Map transforms/casts to the String?
**Question:** Why object sent back to the controller is String or at least acts like a String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/sortableColumn.html:

> params (optional) - a Map containing request parameters

You have: `<g:sortableColumn ... params="['searchParams':searchParams]"/>`. But searchParams is not a proper request parameter because it is itself a map.

Add all your values like id, title, domain, and orderOfSubpage explicitly like:

```
params="[id:searchParams.id, domain:searchParams.domain, ...]"
```

or even:

```
params="${searchParams}"
```